# Stop Azure Pipeline AWS ECR Push task removing forward slash from repository name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am trying to push images from my Azure Pipeline to an AWS ECR containing a forward slash but the pipeline keeps failing as the ECR task seems to be removing the additional forward slash.

My pipeline contains the following:

```
- task: ECRPushImage@1
  displayName: 'Push latest image'
  inputs:
    imageSource: 'imagename'
    sourceImageName: 'appname'
    repositoryName: 'team-name/appname'
    forceDockerNamingConventions: true
```

The build pipeline shows it is removing the forward slash from the repository name:

```
Adding tag '##########.dkr.ecr.#########.amazonaws.com/team-nameappname:latest' to image 'appname:latest'
```

and then finishes with:

`name unknown: The repository with name 'team-nameappname' does not exist in the registry with id '##########'` which is correct because the repo name is `team-name/appname`

If I change my ECR to not contain a forward slash then the task tags my image incorrectly:

```
Adding tag '##########.dkr.ecr.#########.amazonaws.com/team-name:latest' to image 'appname:latest'
```

We have lots of repositories and need to separate them by team name and app name.

I have tried using `//` in the name but that also causes the task to fail.

How can I push my image to an ECR with a forward slash in the name?

Do I need to not use the ECR Push task and use `docker` command instead? Or the AWS CLI task?

I've reviewed the docs and SO but without any luck :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `forceDockerNamingConventions` was causing the problem. Docker naming conventions permit only lowercase letters, numbers, or - and _.

I looked at the source code for the ECR Push Task [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-azure-devops/blob/master/src/tasks/ECRPushImage/TaskOperations.ts) and found the problem.

After setting the flag to false (the last line in the snippet below), the push succeeded with the forward slash in the name

```
- task: ECRPushImage@1
  displayName: 'Push latest image'
  inputs:
    imageSource: 'imagename'
    sourceImageName: 'appname'
    repositoryName: 'team-name/appname'
    forceDockerNamingConventions: false
```

I now have the correct image name in my repository :-)

```
Pushing image '##########.dkr.ecr.#####.amazonaws.com/team-name/appname:latest' to Elastic Container Registry
```

Hope this helps others who come across the same problem.